# Existence of nonparabolic ends

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions, geometric-analysis

Let $M$ a nonparabolic Riemannian manifold. If exists only one nonparabolic end $E$. We would like to know why the subspace of space of bounded harmonic functions with finite Dirichlet integral is the space of constant functions.
Well, by the existence of nonparabolic end $E$, i can build a harmonic $g$ function in $M- \Omega$( where $\Omega$ is subdomain compact of $M$ such that $E$ is a nonparabolic end of $M$). The function $g$ is limited and has finite Dirichlet integral. But i don't know as to use the fact which has only one nonparabolic end of $M$.

Comment: Do you want to prove that if a manifold has only one non-parabolic end, then it has no bounded harmonic functions of finite energy? This is false.

Comment: No, i would like to prove that : If the manifold has only one nonparabolic end then there exists a subspace of space of bounded harmonic functions with finite Dirichlet integral which is the space of constant functions.

Comment: What do you mean? The space of constant functions **is** a subspace of the space of bounded harmonic functions with finite Dirichlet integral.